# iOS 7 find nearest shops around the actual position

Tags: ios, geolocation, maps

I need to find a way to get an list of shops/bars etc. around the actual position of the device. 
I know how to get the position. I also know about the Google API Places. But is there an way to solve this without using third party libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MKLocalSearch API's in MapKit, but you can only do a search for one type of building at a time.

More details can be found in the [MapKit Programming Guide - Enabling Search](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/EnablingSearch/EnablingSearch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH10-SW1)

Otherwise you would have to gather and store the data yourself and query your own system.